# SQL : get values from column depending on boolean expressions in a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query result like this:

```
|bool Expression | Column A | Column B|
+----------------+----------+---------+
|      true      |    2     |   10    |
|      false     |    3     |   10    |
|      true      |    4     |    8    |
```

I need all values of Column B where all boolean expressions from A are true.
The Result I need in this case would be [8] if all were true it would be [8, 10]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can group by columnb:

```
select columnb
from tablename
group by columnb
having min(boolexpression::int) = 1 and max(boolexpression::int) = 1
```

Comment: What if there's more than two rows with the same `columnb`?

Comment: The OP wants distinct values of columnb

Comment: Right... but your solution only takes care of the "min" and "max" rows, so if there are > 2 rows in the database with the same `columnb` value, this could incorrectly return  a row

Comment: If there are > 2 rows with the same columnb and all of them have the value true then  my query will return that value of columnb. So what is the problem?

Comment: Oh right. I'm sorry, you're right. You will need to cast `booleanexpression` to integer (or something) though, I don't think `MIN/MAX(boolean)` is allowed. (Edit: saw you just made this change)

Comment: *As far as* I understood the question, this looks like the correct solution to me.

Answer (score 2):

I would simply use boolean aggregation functions:

```
select b
from t
group by b
having bool_and(bool_expression);
```

As an aside, this will treat `NULL` boolean expressions correctly -- that is, the `b` value will be filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

Why is the following not the solution

```
select b
from table
where expression = true
```